# Ninject is not working in custom validation attribubte in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, data-annotations, customvalidator, ninject.web.mvc

This question is the consequence of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939976/custom-remote-validation-attribute-throwing-error-at-server-side-in-asp-net-mvc).

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Web Application. In my project I am doing remote validation using data annotation to my view model class. I know default remote attribute does not support server validation. I can validate it again in action method. But I do not want to do that it is violating separation of concerns.

So I tried to create custom server client remote validation attribute. I found a code online and I used it. But it is giving me error when server validation is occurred. I am using Ninject for dependency injection. Error occurred because Ninject cannot inject dependencies in validation attribute.

This is my custom remote validation attribute:

```
public class RemoteClientServerAttribute : RemoteAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            // Get the controller using reflection
            Type controller = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}Controller",
                    this.RouteData["controller"].ToString()).ToLower());
            if (controller != null)
            {
                // Get the action method that has validation logic
                MethodInfo action = controller.GetMethods()
                    .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name.ToLower() ==
                        this.RouteData["action"].ToString().ToLower());
                if (action != null)
                {
                    // Create an instance of the controller class
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(controller);
                    // Invoke the action method that has validation logic
                    object response = action.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
                    if (response is JsonResult)
                    {
                        object jsonData = ((JsonResult)response).Data;
                        if (jsonData is bool)
                        {
                            return (bool)jsonData ? ValidationResult.Success :
                                new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
            // If you want the validation to fail, create an instance of ValidationResult
            // return new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessageString);
        }

        public RemoteClientServerAttribute(string routeName)
            : base(routeName)
        {
        }

        public RemoteClientServerAttribute(string action, string controller)
            : base(action, controller)
        {
        }

        public RemoteClientServerAttribute(string action, string controller,
            string areaName)
            : base(action, controller, areaName)
        {
        }
    }
```

This is my controller class

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private ICategoryRepo categoryRepo;

        public CategoryController()
        {

        }

        public CategoryController(ICategoryRepo categoryParam)
        {
            this.categoryRepo = categoryParam;
        }
        .
        .
        //remote validation action
         public JsonResult IsNameUnique(string Name)
        {
            IEnumerable<Category> categories = categoryRepo.Categories.Where(x => x.Name.Trim() == Name);

            Category category = categories.FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(category==null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

When validation passed client side and came to server side, it starts throwing error.

This is the error

[image]

Yes, it is throwing no method found exception because it cannot find constructor without parameters.

I added parameterless constructor like this

```
public CategoryController()
        {
           categoryRepo = new CategoryRepo(); 
        }
```

But the problem is if I do that, the reason I am using Ninject does not make any sense at all. It is making dependency. But if I don't do this way, categoryRepo will throw null exception in IsNameUnique action. So how can I make Ninject work in my custom remote validation attribute?

Comment: Instead of creating the Controller with Activator.CreateInstance, can you ask NInject to give it to you? I don't know enough about NInject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace :

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(controller);
```

with

```
object instance = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(controller);
```

I must point that this is an usage of the controversial [`ServiceLocator`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) pattern. But I hardly see how to do it differently in this attribute.

Comment: What about a filter? I think it's easier to set up DI on a filter's constructor than on an attributes, and it might accomplish the same thing in this case.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. Really appreciate for your help.